# Statsmodel Hierarchical Linear Model With Pairwise Correlated Groups

Tags: python, statsmodels, hierarchical-data, mixed-models, random-effects

I try to estimate a hierarchical model with 30 bookmakers quoting odds for 100 games. Bookmakers are nested in games. There is one observation for each bookmaker and game. My DataFrame looks as follows:

| MatchID | BookmakerID | Odds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1xBet | 1.2 |
| 0 | GGbet | 1.3 |
| 1 | 1xbet | 2.2 |
| 1 | GGbet | 2.4 |

The corresponing `statsmodel` sytnax allowing for both random intercept and slope is

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

re_mod = smf.mixedlm(
    formula="Endog ~ 1 + Exog",
    data=df,
    groups="MatchID",
    re_formula="1 + Exog",
)

re_mod_res = re_mod.fit(reml=True, method=None)
print(re_mod_res.summary())
```

However, the assumption behind is that the bookmaker odds of MatchID 0 are independent of the odds of MatchID 1. While this is plausible for the odds of MatchID 0 quoted by 1xBet and the odds of MatchID 1 quoted by GGbet, it is not for the odds of MatchID 0 quoted by 1xBet and the odds of MatchID 1 quoted by 1xBet because all odds quoted by the same bookmaker share some similarities.

How do I have to modify the syntax to account for this pattern?

Comment: What are `Endog` and `Exog` ? It looks like you need to fit crossed random effects for bother `MatchID` and `BookmakerID`